# why does segmentation fault occur when doing stack in nasm?

Tags: segmentation-fault, stack, nasm

I'm having a problem in doing stack implementation on nasm in 64-bit lubuntu. In other ubuntu OS, it works and runs correctly and when I run it on an online compiler it also runs correctly. I've been thinking if my OS doesn't support stack on nasm or there is just some code that needs to be applied.

```
section .data   
    num dw 0
    x dw 5
    y dw 4
    newline db "",10
    newlineLen equ $-newline

section .bss

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    sub esp,2
        push word[x]
    push word[y]
    call sum
    pop word[num] ;fetch the sum from the stack

    ;convert num for printing
    add word[num],30h

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,num
    mov edx,1
    int 80h

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,newline
    mov edx,newlineLen
    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h

sum:

    mov ebp,esp
    mov ax,[ebp+6] ;5
    add ax,[ebp+4] ;4+5
    mov [ebp+8],ax ;store the result in the space allocated for the sum
    ret 4 ;esp+4
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack operations are most certainly supported on any X86 architecture.  This is assembler, so you're not really using any OS features (unless you call an OS routine).

Segment violations are a sign that you've read or written to a memory location you're not allowed to.  The variation in behavior by platform has something to do with the default memory layouts.

I, also running Ubuntu 12.04 64, get a SEGV.

I went through your program and renamed the registers to the 64-bit names (`eax` becomes `rax`; `ebp` becomes `rbp`; `esp` becomes `rsp`; etc, where you have `e??` make it `r??`) and it ran.

**why does the program emit 0 instead of 9?**

It's because of these lines:

```
mov ax,[ebp+6] ;5
add ax,[ebp+4] ;4+5
mov [ebp+8],ax ;store the result in the space allocated for the sum
```

Change `ax` to `rax` and it will work.

If you move `0x0000000000000005` (a 64-bit value) into `ax` (a 16-bit register) you wind up with `0x0000` (truncated .. oops).  You need instead to refer to the full width of the register, thus `rax`.

*note*: There's probably a directive to force nasm into a 32- or 16- bit mode, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Thanks, there's no more segmentation fault but the result is not right. I changed all e's to r's. The result is zero but it should be 9. The operation is 5+4=9. How come?

Comment: thanks. yours worked also. but the main problem was on how it should be compiled and i have solved it. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `WORD`s?  Unless you have an old 16bit processor, you should be using 32bit registers and parameters since that is what the stack is aligned to.  You are learning Assembly?  Please learn the correct way - save `ebp` before moving `esp` into it!!!!!  Please get out of the habit of using "magic" number and instead use constants for parameters

Why do you `sub esp, 2` at the beginning?  It is unneeded.
Corrected code with correct results:

```
%define sys_exit    1
%define sys_write   4
%define stdout      1

section .data   
num dd 0
x dd 5
y dd 4
newline db "",10
newlineLen equ $-newline

section .bss

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    push    dword[x]
    push    dword[y]
    call    sum
    mov     dword[num], eax 

    ;convert num for printing
    add     dword[num],30h

    mov     eax, sys_write
    mov     ebx, stdout
    mov     ecx, num
    mov     edx, 1
    int     80h

    mov     eax, sys_write
    mov     ebx, stdout
    mov     ecx, newline
    mov     edx, newlineLen
    int     80h

    mov     eax, sys_exit
    xor     ebx, ebx
    int     80h 

sum:
    push    ebp                             ; MUST save ebp!!!
    mov     ebp, esp

    mov     eax, [ebp+12] ;5
    add     eax, [ebp+8] ;4+5
    ;~ Standard way to return a value is in eax
    leave                                   ; same as pop ebp - mov esp, ebp
    ret 4 * 2
```

Comment: thanks for answering but there was just some changes on how it should be compiled. can you help me on this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078695/how-do-you-multiply-word-size-inputs-and-get-its-word-size-product-in-stack?noredirect=1#comment26458641_18078695